# What is the slave address of the STM32 NUCLEO-F401RE?

Tags: stm32, i2c, nucleo

I am currently trying to learn I2C communications with two STM32 NUCLEO-F401RE boards and I am having trouble on how to figure out the slave address of the board. I searched the datasheets and the internet but could not find it and I'm not sure how to determine it.

Comment: Unlike with fixed-function chips, with an MCU the I2C address will be whatever *your software* makes it.  Since your software is not included in the question, this is unanswerable.  Look at your I2C setup code, it will be set somewhere there, likely loaded into a hardware register in the I2C peripheral or at least passed to an I2C setup function.

Answer (score 4):

You should have searched the [Reference Manua](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/5d/b1/ef/b2/a1/66/40/80/DM00096844.pdf/files/DM00096844.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00096844.pdf)l of the controller. But as said the MCU's I2C address can be set from software through dedicated registers.

These are called Own Address Register 1 and 2. For the most simple 7-bit addressing mode you have to clear the **ADDMODE** bit and set any kind of address you want using **ADD[7:1]** bits.

Here are the relevant register descriptions but I suggest to read through the entire I2C chapter of the linked document.

[image]